# Hue-like Legend spectrum with bright colors for a plot

Tags: graphics, color, legending

I use `Hue` to color `ArrayPlot`:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
GraphicsRow[{
 ArrayPlot[gridmatrixpair, Mesh -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> (
    Which[2.0 < #[[1]] < 4.9 && 3*10^8 > #[[2]] > 1*10^6, 
          Hue[(#[[2]] - 1*10^6)*3.344*10^-9],
          True, White
         ] &), 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, AspectRatio -> 2/7, 
   FrameLabel -> {y, x}
 ], 
 Graphics[
   Legend[ColorData["Rainbow"][1 - #1] &, 10, "10^6", "10^8", 
    LegendShadow -> None, LegendLabel -> "Power (a.u.)"]]
}]
```

[image]

But as you see the colors in `ArrayPlot` are brighter than the rainbow colors for the legend. I did not find another `ColorData` object with brighter colors. What can I do, the scale is changing on and on for different notebooks, so the scale spectrum should be part of the `Legend` object.

Comment: Ignoring for the moment that the ``PlotLegends` `` package has been superseded by built in functionality in v9, you are not using the same color distribution in `ArrayPlot` as you are in `Legend`. Have you actually tried using `Hue` in `Legend`? You may have to `Rescale` it, but that shouldn't be an issue. Truthfully, though, if you are using v9, use the [`PlotLegends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotLegends.html) option, it is wholly superior to the ``PlotLegends` `` package.

Comment: @rcollyer So there's a built-in legend function in v9? That's nice! Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the same colour distribution in `ArrayPlot` as you are in `Legend` (or the other way around):

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
GraphicsRow[{
 ArrayPlot[gridmatrixpair, Mesh -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> (
    Which[2.0 < #[[1]] < 4.9 && 3*10^8 > #[[2]] > 1*10^6, 
          Hue[(#[[2]] - 1*10^6)*3.344*10^-9],
          True, White
         ] &), 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, AspectRatio -> 2/7, 
   FrameLabel -> {y, x}
 ], 
 Graphics[
   Legend[ColorData["Hue"][1 - #1] &, 10, "10^6", "10^8", 
    LegendShadow -> None, LegendLabel -> "Power (a.u.)"]]
}]
```

Alternatively, for v9, use the `PlotLegends` option which is much superior to the `PlotLegends` package.